# php OOP: Using eval() to build a string to access $GLOBALS

Tags: php, oop

The following code works and does what I want, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something dumb\awful.

I'm learning OOP and there is a tutorial I started to follow that used a "Config" class to setup some parameters for the program to use. I've noticed something similar in other tutorials. This tutorial though only included a method to retrieve the configuration (it used the $GLOBALS array) not to update it during the run time of the program. I attempted to add this functionality, but resorted to using eval() which I think is a nono? Also it was never explained in the tutorial why the $GLOBALS array was used instead of just using a static variable so I'm confused about that as well.

Here is init.php which gets included in files needing to access the config options:

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '123456',
        'db' => NULL
    ),
    'shell' => array(
        'exe' => 'powershell.exe',
        'args' => array(
            '-NonInteractive',
            '-NoProfile',
            '-NoLogo',
            '-Command'
        )
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

This is the Config.php class which has a get and (my) set method to access the config array. For the set method I build a string like "$GLOBALS['config']['someConfig']['someSubConfig'] = 'newVal';" and use eval to execute it. Ultimately I use it in the program like Config::set('mysql/host','zzzzz');

```
<?php

class Config {
    public static function get($path=NULL) {

        //return all configs if not specified
        $config = $GLOBALS['config'];

        if($path) {
            //parse path to return config
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $element) {
                if(isset($config[$element])) {
                    $config = $config[$element];
                } else {
                    //if config not exist
                    $config = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return $config;
    }

    public static function set($path=NULL,$value=NULL) {

        if($path) {
            //parse path to return config
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            //Start code string for eval
            $globalPosition = '$GLOBALS['."'config'".']';

            foreach($path as $element) {
                $globalPosition .= "['$element']";
            }
            $globalPosition .= "='$value';";
            //End code string

            eval($globalPosition);
            var_dump($GLOBALS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont use eval. Pls dont. Eval is evil. It will eat your soul.

Comment: If `eval()` is the answer, you asked the wrong question... What's wrong with using variable variables? Also, global variables are a bad idea in OOP design. I'd suggest to abort whatever tutorial you're following.

Comment: Why, and also how would I do this the right way? Wasn't sure if eval() was a security risk the way I'm using it here because its tucked away from end users?

Comment: I've heard similarly terrible things about variable variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here are a few caveats:

1. Global variables are rarely a good idea, especially in OOP design (mainly because they couple code very tightly).
2. Please don't use `eval()`.

You can quite easily modify your code to set the variable (by [reference using `=&`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)) without having to use `eval()` at all. For example:

```
public static function set($path = null,$value = null)
{
    if($path)
    {
        //parse path to return config
        $path = explode('/', $path);

        //Start code string for eval
        $setting =& $GLOBALS['config'];

        foreach($path as $element)
        {
            $setting =& $setting[$element];
        }

        $setting = $value;

        var_dump($GLOBALS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks a bunch. I new it would require the value be passed by reference, but just couldn't figure out how. So instead of $GLOBALS could I just use a regular array for this right? Since I'm accessing it by reference I'll always be accessing the same array right?

Comment: Well, I'd say that the values inside your array should be properties of the `Config` class as a minimum. Ideally, they should be abstracted out further into an application class, from which all other classes in the project extend.